# How can SSH ensure a cyphered communication in both directions?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, private-key

There is something I do not get with public/private key authentification.

Let's take the example of using SSH communication between my PC and GitLab. I generate a pair of 2 keys, one private, one public. I can share the public one and give it to GitLab, and I keep the private one secret. The public is used to cypher a message, the private is used to decypher it.

So people (and in particular GitLab) can send me a cyphered message with the public key, and I can decypher it with my private key. That's cool, there is a one-directional communication, from GitLab to my computer. I am happy that GitLab can send me cyphered messages.

But on the other hand, I cannot send cyphered messages to people (and in particular GitLab) because they do not have a private key to decypher it. In such a case, how can SSH send cyphered messages from my PC to GitLab ? How can GitLab be sure that it is indeed me that is sending the message?

I have read something about "The private key is used to sign the message" but I do not understand it. Aren't private keys used only to decypher?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Comment: D-H is not even strictly necessary: all you need is to encrypt a symmetric key with the counterparty's public key to get a bidirectional encrypted channel. D-H is used to provide forward secrecy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you've missed a few steps in SSH:

- Hosts have private/public keys too - you're prompted to accept the key the first time you connect to a new host.
- Host and user keys are used for *authentication*, not for encryption. In authentication, a private key is used to *sign* some data to prove ownership of the corresponding public key.

  - When you connect to a host, the host presents its public key, and you decide whether to trust that key for that host. The host will *sign* some data using its private key to prove it owns that public key.
  - When you go to authenticate as a particular user, you will *sign* some data using your private key, and the server will check that the corresponding public key is authorized (e.g. in `authorized_keys`).
- Session keys for actual encryption are negotiated using a separate protocol, usually one based on [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). Diffie-Hellman is usually done by computing *ephemeral* public/private keys, and requires that the endpoints have authenticated each other to avoid a man-in-the-middle attack.